# Wireless router tl-wr841n went unrepsonsive

Tags: wireless-router, troubleshooting

Suddenly my wireless router `tl-wr841n` went unresponsive. After several reboots i reset it by holding reset button for 8 secs as per manual. Also manual said that by default router should have `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1` address, so I connected my PC directly to router's LAN port (LAN indicators on both router and PC became green as it should) and tried to ping `192.168.0.1` from my PC whose address is `192.168.0.5/24` but got no responce. Then i switched my PC's address to `192.168.1.5/24` and tried to ping `192.168.1.1` but got no responce as well. Is there anything I can try before it goes to trash? I used default firmware and had never upgraded it.

Comment: update your question with the output fo `ipconfig /all`

Answer (score 0):

It possibly got hacked. See [vulnerability list](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/23481/Tp-link-Tl-wr841n.html?vendor_id=11936) for this model.

Try to do 30-30-30 reset: 
Disconnect cable from WAN side.
Turn on router, when it started(wait at list a minute) press and hold reset button for 30 seconds, while still holding reset button disconnect power and wait 30 seconds while continue to hold reset. While still holding reset button pressed, turn on power back and wait 30 seconds again then finally release reset button.

Do not set static IP on your computer, leave it on automatic IP assignment (over DHCP) and when procedures above finished issue from elevated command prompt(run `cmd` as administrator) following commands:

```
ipconfig /release
```

then

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Check if IP assigned:

```
ipconfig /all
```

If you got something assigned, try to ping default gateway that shown in the last  `ipconfig /all`, if you got reply, then router recovered.

Don't connect WAN cable yet, go online from some other place and download latest firmware and upgrade your router before you allow your router go online.